# Objective C Array return Cell value of a particular Row

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

Is there a single command in Xcode that allows you to return the value of a specific cell in a specific row?

```
Row 1 | Cell 1 | Cell 2 | Cell 3
Row 2 | Cell 1 | Cell 2 | Cell 3
Row 3 | Cell 1 | Cell 2 | Cell 3
```

E.g. I want the value of Cell 3 in Row 3.

Many thanks.

Comment: I assume you are using NSArray, how do you define it?

Comment: arrayLocations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:99];

Comment: Then the contents are pulled from a database:

while([results next]) {
        recno++;
        classLocations * locations = [[classLocations alloc] init];
        locations.locationID    = [results intForColumn:@"ID"];
        locations.location      = [results stringForColumn:@"NAME"];
        locations.longitude     = [results stringForColumn:@"LONGITUDETEXT"];
        locations.latitude      = [results stringForColumn:@"LATITUDETEXT"];
        locations.altitude      = [results stringForColumn:@"ALTITUDETEXT"];
        [arrayLocations addObject:locations];
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you assign multiple cells for a single row? I think you can't. `cellForRowAtIndexPath` should return only one `UITableViewCell` instance.

**Note:**

You can get a `UITableViewCell` from a specic row using the below code

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:nowIndex];
```